# Is this possible on wordpress newsletter

Tags: wordpress, newsletter

Good day, 
I need some advice if this is possible on wordpress?  I have a classified site and I want to create a newsletter that would have multiple categories each category would just have a list of title that has links to the item page.

The hard part is I need a check box on the registration and user profile page that will enable them to select which category they want on their newsletter and uncheck which one they don’t need. The reason for this is the list on each category can be too many and users might not want to see listing about ex. community or announcement etc.

Another feature that I need is for paid listing to stay on the newsletter  for the duration of its package and for free listing to only show the day it was posted even though it has 5 days to stay on the site

I am open to use any options like mailchimp, awebber etc. as long as it works

Ex. 
Hot Deal <-Category
1.) New Arrival comfort footwear
Forsale <-Category
1.) Xbox one fresh inbox
2.) Ps4 brand new

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/subscribe-to-category/)
which will help you to make users subscribing to category.
That plugin lets a user subscribe and unsubscribe to posts within a certain category or categories.
Subscribers will recieve an e-mail with a link to the actual post.
And the post type may be anything like product or news etc ;)
But you may endup doing some customize coding to get what exactly you are looking for.